# Connect two ttySx devices on the same machine

Tags: tty, serial-port

I'm just wondering, whether it is possible to connect `/dev/ttyS0` with a virtual device node (e.g. a created with `mknod /dev/ttyTest`) so that the output from `ttyS0` is sent to `ttyTest`.

I would like to start two instances of minicom and to "chat" with each other on the same machine. So whatever I type in minicom #1 can be read in minicom #2.

Comment: I guess something with `socat` and a `pty`. I don't have time to elaborate/test it: http://justcheckingonall.wordpress.com/2009/06/09/howto-vsp-socat/

Comment: thanks for the link. that looks pretty promising. i'll have a look at it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to the link from @LatinSuD I got the solution.
And even the explanation in the link said word by word:

> Creating pairs of virtual serial ports (VSP), is quite often wanted feature, 
>   yet it’s hard to find a solution online (try Googling it)…

So I don't feel that dumb ;P

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=0 pty,raw,echo=0
```

does the magic and creates two virtual devices which are connected to each other.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

It can be done without any problem. I did it many times to play with rs232.

What you had to watch:

- the ports must have the same settings (baud rate, data-stop-parity)
- the cable must be good (rs232 in such experiment settings have very often some hardware problem)

The best if you use the same miniconf config, only with different tty ports.

Comment: nargh, maybe i wasn't specific enough. I dont have two serial ports on my machine. I only have one. But i don't really want to use the hardware-serial-port. I need two virtual devices, which are connected together. And my question was: How to create two virtualy connected tty-Devices?